# Why are small appliance questions off topic?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question about fixing a small appliance : [How to replace Blender's Drive Coupling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/140819/25798)

A comment said this is off topic. When I read the [help section](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
it says questions about small appliances are off topic. I couldn't quite figure out if its just questions about operation of a small appliance or any and all questions about small appliances are off topic.

I want to understand *why*, on a diy site would the question about fixing a small appliance be off-topic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a DIY **Home Improvement** site.  We cover aspects of building, repairing, and maintaining a home.  While a small appliance (blender) might be found *in* a home, it's not actually *part* of the home.  Therefore it's off topic.

Unfortunately, in this day and age (at least in the US), most folks don't repair small appliances.  And even if they wanted to, most small appliances are designed and built to be "unserviceable". Because of this, there's not many "experts" in this area anymore. Which means you'll have trouble getting helpful answers to these types of questions.